# font colour with if and else ruby on rails tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So i'm a ror beginner and I'm trying to do this:
I have ratings out of 100
I'd like to do
if rating is between 66 and 100, background colour is green
if rating is between 33 and 66, background colour is orange
if rating is between 00 and 33, background colour is red

also my ratings are the average of other ratings so the number aren't actually in the DB, they're just the result of this:

```
<%= number_with_precision(show.reviews.average("rating"), :precision => 0)
```

any tutorials around that might explain how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `between?` method.

```
if rating.between?(00, 33)
  #red 
elsif rating.between?(33,66)
  #organ
elsif rating.between?(66, 100)
  #green
else
  #some other color
```

Comment: probably `between?` is inclusive! so you may not compare same values in two logic!

Comment: where would that go ? View ?  (I started ror 14 days ago)

Comment: Yay! I got this to work.  Thank you!
What I actually wanted to do was change the colour of the rating background so a bit more work ahead but thank you for this.

Comment: This logic should be in your helper file , as some helper methods. You should then call that method in your view. Better coding

Comment: @Ross I realised that I had to write this many times and that there had to be a better way, can you specify how to do this ?

Comment: Check out this blog good enough to start with http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using `between?` here. It only makes the code longer. Why not just use `>` and `<`?

Comment: @Mischa if >66 green but what for between 33 and 66 ?

Comment: @CharlieAllombert, `if rating < 34 'red' elsif rating > 66 'green' else 'orange' end` Sorry, I can't put line breaks in comments, but I think you get the point.